# Remove Array by Value - Real Time Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a Real-Time web app, receiving push events from Node JS, adding to and removing from an array in Javascript.  I have found after doing the typical splice to remove the item by the matching value's index, the size of the array decreases as expected, but sometimes the element isn't getting removed.

My theory is the real time data is adding to and removing from the array in parallel for different places in the array, and sometimes the index position becomes out of date at the moment in time it's about to do the splice.

How can I remove an item from an array by value in real time if the index is always changing?

```
for(var i=0; i<data.geometries.length; i++) {
    if(data.geometries[i].id == item.id) { //Found Item in Array
        //do some stuff
        data.geometries.splice(i,1); //Remove Geometry                                                                                                           
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.filter` method:

```
var result = data.geometries.filter(function (e) {
  return e.id !== item.id;
});
```

Comment: Well, I have the element, it matches by value.  It's just that when I go to splice it, the array has changed, and the index no longer matches.  How can I remove it by value?

Comment: you shouldnt change that array. Just make a new one. like xdazz writes

Comment: That makes sense, and solved the issue the easiest.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a sparse array, where you can have an array with gaps or holes. Using splice to modify the array will affect any indexes that come after the removed element. So, you could use a regular array as a sparse array, but you would delete items differently. For example:

```
// array to act as sparse array
var set = [1,2,3,4];

// remove an item by value
var pos = set.indexOf(3);
if (pos !== -1) {
    // don't 'splice', just set to undefined
    set[pos] = undefined;
}
// add an item
if (set.indexOf(5) == -1) {
    set.push(5);
}
// to get the values from sparse array
var values = set.filter(function(v) { return typeof v !== 'undefined' });
console.log(values);
// => [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

This way, your indexes stay the same across parallel processes and threads.

Comment: This sounds promising, giving it a try... thank you!

Comment: I think this is a great answer too!  The other answer happened to work out the easiest.  Thank you!  I really appreciate everyone's help.